# Flow erroring "cant resolve module" when importing node modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules, flowtype

I recently added this to my flow config due to tons of errors related to node modules that flow picks up

```
[ignore]
.*/node_modules/.*
```

This solved those errors, but introduced new one. Now every module I import results in an error where flow says it can't resolve it, hence leading me to think this is due to that ignore rule I added.

Is there a way to fix this because here removing this line just introduces different kind of error, keeping it in still makes it error.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: It's not supposed to cause this kind of error, is it possible that those dependencies are not actually in node_modules?

Answer (score 9):

It's a little late now, but for anyone stumbling along this question in the future: you shouldn't ignore your node_modules folder. Flow is supposed to read from that folder and analyze the files inside it.

Comment: @Michael, me too, and I spent half a day trying to figure out what went wrong :)

Comment: @JamesKraus then how to remove the error given in this question.

Comment: @Raj, you would need to post a more specific question. There's a lot of reasons why this can happen.

Comment: @JamesKraus thanks for replying: here is the question I have posted for the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164591/prevent-flowtype-to-check-error-in-node-modules

Comment: Learned something new and useful today. Thanks @JamesKraus

Answer (score 5):

Actually this is because of the module has no typed definitions. So we can just use flow-typed to create any definition.

1. Run `yarn global add flow-typed` to install flow-typed globally.
2. Go to project folder: `flow-typed install`
3. Close your terminal and try to run `npm run flow` again. That's it.

Ref: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5935